# Drupal 7 Multilingual Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am building a site in English and French. I am using field translations as I have a comment form attached to the articles and I want people to comment and see all comments no matter which language they view the site in.

Within the site I am displaying the list of articles via a view. Some of the articles are only in English. Is there a way to stop French users from seeing the English only articles in their view? At the moment articles in English and French display the teasers in their relevant user selected language, but English only articles display in English for French user instead of simply disappearing.

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you added the `Content: Language` to the `Filter criteria` ?

Answer (score 1):

You only need one view to filter content depending on the user's current language.

With regard to your requirement, one easy way could be to set a taxonomy such as
- English only
- French only
- Both languages

and use that to filter your views accordingly.

There is probably a more elegant way, check the following article on drupal.org
[HowTo: Basic Internationalization setup](http://drupal.org/node/1268692). A multilingual setup involves so many various steps and modules, also there are many possible recipes.